# How do I convert the 2 control points of a cubic curve to the single control point of a quadratic curve?

Tags: geometry, bezier

Having searched the web, I see various people in various forums alluding to approximating a cubic curve with a quadratic one. But I can't find the formula.

What I want is this:

input: startX, startY, control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y, endX, endY
output: startX, startY, controlX, controlY, endX, endY

Actually, since the starting and ending points will be the same, all I really need is...

input: startX, startY, control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y, endX, endY
output: controlX, controlY

Comment: BTW. if you want to approximate "by hand", you can try it here: http://lib.ivank.net/?p=demos&d=bezier

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned, going from 4 control points to 3 is normally going to be an approximation.  There's only one case where it will be exact - when the cubic bezier curve is actually a degree-elevated quadratic bezier curve.

You can use the degree elevation equations to come up with an approximation.  It's simple, and the results are usually pretty good.

Let's call the control points of the cubic Q0..Q3 and the control points of the quadratic P0..P2.  Then for degree elevation, the equations are:

```
Q0 = P0
Q1 = 1/3 P0 + 2/3 P1
Q2 = 2/3 P1 + 1/3 P2
Q3 = P2
```

In your case you have Q0..Q3 and you're solving for P0..P2.  There are two ways to compute P1 from the equations above:

```
P1 = 3/2 Q1 - 1/2 Q0
P1 = 3/2 Q2 - 1/2 Q3
```

If this is a degree-elevated cubic, then both equations will give the same answer for P1.  Since it's likely not, your best bet is to average them. So,

```
P1 = -1/4 Q0 + 3/4 Q1 + 3/4 Q2 - 1/4 Q3
```

To translate to your terms:

```
controlX = -0.25*startX + .75*control1X + .75*control2X -0.25*endX
```

Y is computed similarly - the dimensions are independent, so this works for 3d (or n-d).

This will be an approximation.  If you need a better approximation, one way to get it is by subdividing the initial cubic using the deCastlejau algorithm, and then degree-reduce each segment.  If you need better continuity, there are other approximation methods that are less quick and dirty.

Comment: The main reference I use is from a CAGD class I took: http://tom.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/  Chapter 2 covers Bezier curves.

Comment: Please, where you've got this `P1 = -1/4 Q0 + 3/4 Q1 + 3/4 Q2 - 1/4 Q3` from? It works very well...

Comment: @EcirHana I got that equation by averaging the other two equations for P1.  In other words, if I define P1a = 3/2 Q1 - 1/2 Q0 and P1b = 3/2 Q2 - 1/2 Q3, then P1 = 1/2 (P1a + P1b).  If I simplify terms, I get P1 = -1/4 Q0 + 3/4 Q1 + 3/4 Q2 - 1/4 Q3.  P1a and P1b are derived from the degree elevation equations up top.

Comment: You are approximating a "curve as a function", not "a curve as an image". See here: https://jsfiddle.net/o15qky2r/1/ . There are two cubic curves (red), quad curves according to your formula (yellow) and better quad curves (black).

Comment: Yes, the further a cubic is from a degree-elevated quadratic in both geometry and parameterization, the worse this simple approximation will be. There are lots of approximation techniques, which have different strengths and weaknesses - it would be helpful if you added the method you used as an answer to this question

Answer (score 5):

The cubic can have loops and cusps, which quadratic cannot have. This means that there are not simple solutions nearly never. If cubic is already a quadratic, then the simple solution exists. Normally you have to divide cubic to parts that are quadratics. And you have to decide what are the critical points for subdividing.

http://fontforge.org/bezier.html#ps2ttf says:
"Other sources I have read on the net suggest checking the cubic spline for points of inflection (which quadratic splines cannot have) and forcing breaks there. To my eye this actually makes the result worse, it uses more points and the approximation does not look as close as it does when ignoring the points of inflection. So I ignore them."

This is true, the inflection points (second derivatives of cubic) are not enough. But if you take into account also local extremes (min, max) which are the first derivatives of cubic function, and force breaks on those all, then the sub curves are all quadratic and can be presented by quadratics.

I tested the below functions, they work as expected (find all critical points of cubic and divides the cubic to down-elevated cubics). When those sub curves are drawn, the curve is exactly the same as original cubic, but for some reason, when sub curves are drawn as quadratics, the result is nearly right, but not exactly.

So this answer is not for strict help for the problem, but those functions provide a starting point for cubic to quadratic conversion.

To find both local extremes and inflection points, the following `get_t_values_of_critical_points()` should provide them. The

```
function compare_num(a,b) {
  if (a < b) return -1;
  if (a > b) return 1;
  return 0;
}

function find_inflection_points(p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y,p3x,p3y,p4x,p4y)
{
  var ax = -p1x + 3*p2x - 3*p3x + p4x;
  var bx = 3*p1x - 6*p2x + 3*p3x;
  var cx = -3*p1x + 3*p2x;

  var ay = -p1y + 3*p2y - 3*p3y + p4y;
  var by = 3*p1y - 6*p2y + 3*p3y;
  var cy = -3*p1y + 3*p2y;
  var a = 3*(ay*bx-ax*by);
  var b = 3*(ay*cx-ax*cy);
  var c = by*cx-bx*cy;
  var r2 = b*b - 4*a*c;
  var firstIfp = 0;
  var secondIfp = 0;
  if (r2>=0 && a!==0)
  {
    var r = Math.sqrt(r2);
    firstIfp = (-b + r) / (2*a);
    secondIfp = (-b - r) / (2*a);
    if ((firstIfp>0 && firstIfp<1) && (secondIfp>0 && secondIfp<1))
    {
      if (firstIfp>secondIfp)
      {
        var tmp = firstIfp;
        firstIfp = secondIfp;
        secondIfp = tmp;
      }
      if (secondIfp-firstIfp >0.00001)
        return [firstIfp, secondIfp];
      else return [firstIfp];
    }
    else if (firstIfp>0 && firstIfp<1)
      return [firstIfp];
    else if (secondIfp>0 && secondIfp<1)
    {
      firstIfp = secondIfp;
      return [firstIfp];
    }
    return [];
  }
  else return [];
}

function get_t_values_of_critical_points(p1x, p1y, c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, p2x, p2y) {
    var a = (c2x - 2 * c1x + p1x) - (p2x - 2 * c2x + c1x),
    b = 2 * (c1x - p1x) - 2 * (c2x - c1x),
    c = p1x - c1x,
    t1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a,
    t2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a,
    tvalues=[];
    Math.abs(t1) > "1e12" && (t1 = 0.5);
    Math.abs(t2) > "1e12" && (t2 = 0.5);
    if (t1 >= 0 && t1 <= 1 && tvalues.indexOf(t1)==-1) tvalues.push(t1)
    if (t2 >= 0 && t2 <= 1 && tvalues.indexOf(t2)==-1) tvalues.push(t2);

    a = (c2y - 2 * c1y + p1y) - (p2y - 2 * c2y + c1y);
    b = 2 * (c1y - p1y) - 2 * (c2y - c1y);
    c = p1y - c1y;
    t1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a;
    t2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a;
    Math.abs(t1) > "1e12" && (t1 = 0.5);
    Math.abs(t2) > "1e12" && (t2 = 0.5);
    if (t1 >= 0 && t1 <= 1 && tvalues.indexOf(t1)==-1) tvalues.push(t1);
    if (t2 >= 0 && t2 <= 1 && tvalues.indexOf(t2)==-1) tvalues.push(t2);

    var inflectionpoints = find_inflection_points(p1x, p1y, c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, p2x, p2y);
    if (inflectionpoints[0]) tvalues.push(inflectionpoints[0]);
    if (inflectionpoints[1]) tvalues.push(inflectionpoints[1]);

    tvalues.sort(compare_num);
    return tvalues;
};
```

And when you have those critical t values (which are from range 0-1), you can divide the cubic to parts:

```
function CPoint()
{
  var arg = arguments;
  if (arg.length==1)
  {
    this.X = arg[0].X;
    this.Y = arg[0].Y;
  }
  else if (arg.length==2)
  {
    this.X = arg[0];
    this.Y = arg[1];
  }
}

function subdivide_cubic_to_cubics()
{
    var arg = arguments;
    if (arg.length!=9) return [];
    var m_p1 = {X:arg[0], Y:arg[1]};
  var m_p2 = {X:arg[2], Y:arg[3]};
  var m_p3 = {X:arg[4], Y:arg[5]};
  var m_p4 = {X:arg[6], Y:arg[7]};
  var t = arg[8];
  var p1p = new CPoint(m_p1.X + (m_p2.X - m_p1.X) * t,
                       m_p1.Y + (m_p2.Y - m_p1.Y) * t);
  var p2p = new CPoint(m_p2.X + (m_p3.X - m_p2.X) * t,
                       m_p2.Y + (m_p3.Y - m_p2.Y) * t);
  var p3p = new CPoint(m_p3.X + (m_p4.X - m_p3.X) * t,
                       m_p3.Y + (m_p4.Y - m_p3.Y) * t);
  var p1d = new CPoint(p1p.X + (p2p.X - p1p.X) * t,
                       p1p.Y + (p2p.Y - p1p.Y) * t);
  var p2d = new CPoint(p2p.X + (p3p.X - p2p.X) * t,
                       p2p.Y + (p3p.Y - p2p.Y) * t);
  var p1t = new CPoint(p1d.X + (p2d.X - p1d.X) * t,
                       p1d.Y + (p2d.Y - p1d.Y) * t);
  return [[m_p1.X, m_p1.Y, p1p.X, p1p.Y, p1d.X, p1d.Y, p1t.X, p1t.Y],
          [p1t.X, p1t.Y, p2d.X, p2d.Y, p3p.X, p3p.Y, m_p4.X, m_p4.Y]];
}
```

`subdivide_cubic_to_cubics()` in above code divides an original cubic curve to two parts by the value t. Because `get_t_values_of_critical_points()` returns t values as an array sorted by t value, you can easily traverse all t values and get the corresponding sub curve. When you have those divided curves, you have to divide the 2nd sub curve by the next t value.

When all splitting is proceeded, you have the control points of all sub curves. Now there are left only the cubic control point conversion to quadratic. Because all sub curves are now down-elevated cubics, the corresponding quadratic control points are easy to calculate. The first and last of quadratic control points are the same as cubic's (sub curve) first and last control point and the middle one is found in the point, where lines P1-P2 and P4-P3 crosses.

Comment: “for some reason, when sub curves are drawn as quadratics, the result is nearly right, but not exactly” the reason is pretty clear: each sub-curve is still a cubic, and therefore can only be approximated by a quadratic, not represented exactly.

Answer (score 4):

**Conventions/terminology**

- Cubic defined by: P1/2 - anchor points, C1/C2 control points
- |x| is the euclidean norm of x
- mid-point approx of cubic: a quad that shares the same anchors with the cubic and has the control point at C = (3·C2 - P2 + 3·C1 - P1)/4

**Algorithm**

1. pick an absolute precision (*prec*)
2. Compute the Tdiv as the root of (cubic) equation sqrt(3)/18 · |P2 - 3·C2 + 3·C1 - P1|/2 · Tdiv ^ 3 = *prec*
3. if Tdiv < 0.5 divide the cubic at Tdiv. First segment [0..Tdiv] can be approximated with by a quadratic, with a defect less than *prec*, by the mid-point approximation. Repeat from step 2 with the second resulted segment (corresponding to 1-Tdiv)
4. 0.5<=Tdiv<1 - simply divide the cubic in two. The two halves can be approximated by the  mid-point approximation
5. Tdiv>=1 - the entire cubic can be approximated by the mid-point approximation

The "magic formula" at step 2 is demonstrated (with interactive examples) [on this page](http://caffeineowl.com/graphics/2d/vectorial/cubic2quad01.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another derivation of tfinniga's answer:
First see Wikipedia [Bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve)
for the formulas for quadratic and cubic Bezier curves (also nice animations):

```
Q(t) = (1-t)^2 P0 + 2 (1-t) t Q + t^2 P3
P(t) + (1-t)^3 P0 + 3 (1-t)^2 t P1 + 3 (1-t) t^2 P2 + t^3 P3
```

Require these to match at the middle, t = 1/2:

```
(P0 + 2 Q + P3) / 4 = (P0 + 3 P1 + 3 P2 + P3) / 8  
=> Q = P1 + P2 - (P0 + P1 + P2 + P3) / 4
```

(Q written like this has a geometric interpretation:

```
Pmid = middle of P0 P1 P2 P3  
P12mid = midway between P1 and P2  
draw a line from Pmid to P12mid, and that far again: you're at Q.
```

Hope this makes sense -- draw a couple of examples.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you'll have to use multiple quadratic curves - many cases of cubic curves can't be even vaguely approximated with a single quadratic curve.

There is a good article discussing the problem, and a number of ways to solve it, at http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/articles/cubic_bezier_in_flash.htm (including interactive demonstrations).

Answer (score 1):

I should note that Adrian's solution is great for single cubics, but when the cubics are segments of a smooth cubic spline, then using his midpoint approximation method causes slope continuity at the nodes of the segments to be lost. So the method described at http://fontforge.org/bezier.html#ps2ttf is much better if you are working with font glyphs or for any other reason you want to retain the smoothness of the curve (which is most probably the case).

Even though this is an old question, many people like me will see it in search results, so I'm posting this here.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably draw a series of curves instead of trying to draw one curve using a different alg. Sort of like drawing two half circles to make up a whole circle.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for opensource Postcript font to Truetype font converters. I'm sure they have it. Postscript uses cubic bezier curves, whereas Truetype uses quadratic bezier curves. Good luck.